# Stereographic projection $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1\longrightarrow\mathcal{S}^2$ between complex projective line and $2$-sphere is continuous

Tags: complex-geometry, projective-space, stereographic-projections

The stereographic projection between  the $2$-sphere $\mathcal{S}^2$ and the complex projective line $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ can be given by the following (well-defined) map $f:\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1\longrightarrow\mathcal{S}^2$ defined by $f[z:w]=\left(\frac{2\text{Re}(w\overline{z})}{|w|^2+|z|^2},\frac{2\text{Im}(w\overline{z})}{|w|^2+|z|^2},\frac{|w|^2-|z|^2}{|w|^2+|z|^2}\right)$. I want to show that this $f$ is a homeomorphism, but I am stuck when trying to prove its continuity. Showing that the preimage of an open subset of the sphere is an open subset op the complex projective line does not seem to be the right approach to this problem. Does someone know which approach is best here to show that $f$ is continuous? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show that the composition $\mathbb C^2\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb C\mathbb P^1\xrightarrow fS^2$ is continuous, and then use that $\mathbb C\mathbb P^1$ has the quotient topology with respect to the natural map $\mathbb C^2\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb C\mathbb P^1$ to conclude that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you tell me more explicitly how to prove continuity of the composition, so continuity of the map $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow\mathcal{S}^2$? If the composition is continuous, does that mean that the two functions must be continuous?

Comment: The map $\mathbb C^2\setminus\{0\}\to S^2$ is given by the same formula you have written. It is continuous because it is built from a bunch of continuous functions. That is, $\mathrm{Re}(z),\mathrm{Im}(z),|z|$,etc. are all continuous functions, and this map is formed by taking sums, products, and quotients of these, so it is continuous as well.